# PHP MySql: Why does my select option not display the number in the dropdown select?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Why does my select option not display the number in the dropdown select? What's wrong?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    if(!$result){
      die('Query FAILED');
}
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-6">

      <form action="login_create.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select name="id" id = " ">
                            <?php
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                  $id = $row['id'];
                              echo "<option value='$id'>$id</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" 
value="UPDATE">
         </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's `$mysqli` where is this defined at....

Answer (score 1):

You must call Database connection...

Replace

1. LOCALHOST with your host (For WAMP/XAMPP: localhost)
2. USERNAME with Database username (For WAMP/XAMPP: root)
3. PASSWORD with Database Password (For WAMP/XAMPP: )[Blank]
4. DATABASE with Database name

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli('LOCALHOST','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DATABASE')

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

   if(!$result){

       die('Query FAILED');

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to the DB, what's this value

```
$mysqli
```

It's never defined/set in your post.  Therefore I have to assume you never connected to the DB.

First place to start always, is turn on error reporting

```
<?php
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     error_reporting(-1); //or E_ALL
     ... other code ...
```

If you do that and it says, something like.

> Warning undefined variable $mysql

Then you will know.